# [ERROR] IMU_node (help-me)

Tags: ros, tutorial, microstrain

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I'm trying to use the imu_node , but by following the tutorial contained herein : http://wiki.ros.org/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/Tutorials/UsingTheIMUNode , I encounter the following message:

```
[ ERROR] [ 1448558982.111227055 ] : Device / dev / ttyUSB0 is already locked . Try ' lsof | grep / dev / ttyUSB0 'to find other processes que currently have the port open . (in microstrain_3dmgx2_imu :: IMU : OpenPort ) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/Troubleshooting .
```

I've tried several exits , but it still fails. Algem could give me some way ?

Inertia-Link and 3DM-GX2 sensor.

---

Edit: Hello, thank you for responding. I've tried you-plugging  the device. How could I kill a process? Is there any way to choose the input the turns on? That would solve?

when I do `lsof|grep /dev/ttyUSB0`, i received this information:

```
rafael@rafael-pc:~$ lsof|grep /dev/ttyUSB0
imu_node  21051           rafael    9uW     CHR              188,0      0t0  5244268 /dev/ttyUSB0
imu_node  21051 21060     rafael    9uW     CHR              188,0      0t0  5244268 /dev/ttyUSB0
imu_node  21051 21061     rafael    9uW     CHR              188,0      0t0  5244268 /dev/ttyUSB0
imu_node  21051 21062     rafael    9uW     CHR              188,0      0t0  5244268 /dev/ttyUSB0
imu_node  21051 21067     rafael    9uW     CHR              188,0      0t0  5244268 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:**

Now I see that there are no processes using the port. The other possible reason is given: "This sometimes happens if you are not connected to an IMU". The USB Base Station is connected to the USB port and the sensor is also connected (but not in pc), have to do something else? I do not understand the error, since there are not processes trying to use the port. Thank you!

asdfasdf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221588/%5Berror%5D-imu_node-(help-me)/) by [rafael_palma](https://answers.ros.org/users/25186/rafael_palma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-30**:
Rafael: please don't post answers when you only want to post an update. Edit your original question with that new information. Use the *edit* link/button for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error tells that /dev/ttyUSB0 device is used by some other processes. As it suggests, you can check the output of  `lsof | grep /dev/ttyUSB0` command to see any relevant processes and kill them before running this.

You may also try re-plugging the device.

**UPDATE:**

You can run `rosnode kill imu_node` to kill your previous node if it hangs.
If you do not succeed with this check [this topic](http://answers.ros.org/question/11765/rosnode-kill-doesnt-kill-a-node/).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rafael_palma](https://answers.ros.org/users/25186/rafael_palma/) on 2015-11-29**:
Hello, thank you for responding. I answered your comment just above,  could help me??